# what is the correct way to use onclick in this part of javascript?

Tags: javascript, onclick

so i am making a simply game use javascript, to practice my skill(yep i am a beginner on js) .

what am i trying to achive in this code is , there are nine buttons in total, and those button will turn red randomly, then turn back normal after 1s, when user clicked the red button, game score +1 ， otherwise nothing happen .

so i come up with code like this :

the problem is , when i add onclick to code, when button turn red , gameScore will automaticlly plus one , i'm not sure which part i done wrong, can someone help me out? i stuck on this problem for one day already...

SNIPPET:

```js
var gameScore = 0;

      function start() {

      gameTime();

      //random number

      var popTime = Math.random() * 200 + 800;
      setInterval("ratPop()", popTime);
      console.log(popTime);
    };

    //rat pop out 
    function ratPop() {
      var ratNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
      var rats = document.getElementsByClassName('hitArea');
      rats[ratNumber].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      rats[ratNumber].onclick = pointsCount(); // this is the problem
      setTimeout(
        function goBack() {
          rats[ratNumber].style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        }, 1000
      );
    };

    //timer
    function gameTime() {
      var number = document.getElementById('timer');
      var count = 60;
      number.innerHTML = count;
      var colock = null;
      colock = setInterval(function() {
        if (count > 0) {
          count = count - 1;
          number.innerHTML = count;
        } else {
          clearInterval(colock);
        }
      }, 1000);
    }


    //score
    function pointsCount() {
      var score = document.getElementById('score');
      gameScore = gameScore + 1;
      score.innerHTML = gameScore;
    };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
    scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    

    <div id = 'playGround'>
        <ul id='rats'>
            <li><button type="button"  class = 'hitArea' id = 
    'rat0'>rat0</button></li>
            <li><button type="button"  class = 'hitArea' id = 
    'rat1'>rat1</button></li>
            <li><button type="button"  class = 'hitArea' id = 
    'rat2'>rat2</button></li>
            <li><button type="button"  class = 'hitArea' id = 
    'rat3'>rat3</button></li>
            <li><button type="button"  class = 'hitArea' id = 
    'rat4'>rat4</button></li>
            <li><button type="button"  class = 'hitArea' id = 
    'rat5'>rat5</button></li>
            <li><button type="button"  class = 'hitArea' id = 
    'rat6'>rat6</button></li>
            <li><button type="button"  class = 'hitArea' id = 
    'rat7'>rat7</button></li>
            <li><button type="button"  class = 'hitArea' id = 
    'rat8'>rat8</button></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div> 


    <div id = 'controlPanel'>
        <button onclick= "start()">GameStart!</button>
        <button>GameStop</button>
        <button>GameOver</button>
    </div> 
    

    <div>
            <h1>time：<span id='timer'>60</span></h1>
        </div> 


    <div id = 'scoreConter'>
        <h1>score：<span id='score'>0</span></h1>
    </div> 
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you please post your HTML as well? Moreover `pointsCount()` --> This will make a function call and not just an assignment. Hence it increments automatically without actually being clicked. You can change that to `pointsCount` only without brackets.

Comment: Please create a snippet with your html. Here is guide to create snippet https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rats[ratNumber].onclick = pointsCount; //here
```

Also, you need to remove the 'onclick' after it goes back to white.

```
rats[ratNumber].removeAttribute("onclick");
```

Comment: glad it helped! Also, mentioning it as a solution to your question will help someone having this same problem find the correct solution easily in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code into this:

```
rats[ratNumber].onclick = function() {
    pointsCount();
}
```

or:

```
rats[ratNumber].addEventListener("click", pointsCount);
```